# How to find the last month data based on current date?

Tags: pandas, datetime

Is there any way based on a date to take the last one month data? I have searched a lot but I can't find a good and precise solution. If the current date is on index 420 the date is 2012-01-09. I want to have a data frame with data from 2011-12-09 until 2012-01-09.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

times = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2012-01-01', '2012-04-01', freq='30min'), columns=['date'])
times['date'] = pd.to_datetime(times['date'])
times['value'] = np.random.randint(1, 6, times.shape[0])

months = times.iloc[0:420].sort_values(by='date', ascending=True).set_index('date').last('1M')
```

Using the .last command the results end on 2012-01-01 as this is the last month. I understand it but is there any way to find the last one month data without using timedelta or relative delta? In the case of both if a date is missing then an error appears which is also a problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I have tested your suggestion but the results are still the same as before. Nothing changed.

Comment: You can use  pd.DateOffset and reindex/

Comment: It is doing what you want exactly. The perceived "weirdness" comes from your data. 30 minutes per period mean 48 periods per day or 1440 periods per month (assuming 30-day month). 420 periods is too short to reach back a whole month. Try changing your `iloc` to something like `iloc[0:2000]` and you will get what you want

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is pd.Period. You can convert all of your datetimes to a month period and then search using that

```py
# turn your datetimes to month periods
times["month"] = times[times["date"].dt.to_period("m")]

# turn your search date to a period
your_date = pd.Period(your_date, "m")

# search times
times[times["month"] == your_date]
```